# PHP | Upload Excel into SQL Databse - Getting Error Undefined Offset

Tags: php

Okay, I am getting a Undefiend Offset Error on [1] and [2] which should be $Event_Date and $Event_Organization.

The weird thing is that I also have it set to display the row and the data entered for said row. It even displays this data correctly via echo.

Another strange thing is I have a second CSV upload area on the site that is a carbon copy that work correctly. The only differance is the $_GET ($Type) for the url passed Variable.

Maybe I should change it to a $_POST instead? They only thing $Type does is determine if it is a Bulk Entry or Single Entry.

Edit 1
I changed it from a $_GET to a $_POST by adding a hidden field in the form on the prior page, and still received the same error.

```
$Type = $_GET["Type"];

if($Type == 'Bulk')
{
    if ($_FILES['Excel']['size'] > 0) 
    { 
        //get the csv file 
        $file = $_FILES['Excel']['tmp_name']; 
        $handle = fopen($file,"r"); 

        //loop through the csv file and insert into database 
        $column_headers = array();
        $row_count = 0;
        $Count = 1;

        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 100000, ",")) !== FALSE) 
        {
            if ($row_count != 0)
            {
                //user input
                $Event_Name = $data[0];
                $Event_Date = $data[1];
                $Event_Organization = $data[2];

                echo ' '.$Event_Name.' '.$Event_Date.' '.$Event_Organization.'<br> <br>';

                //Add Account Informaion | Login
                $Create_Event_Query ='INSERT INTO Event(Event_Name,
                                      Event_Date,   Event_Organization)
                                      VALUES(?,?,?)';
                $Create_Event_stmt = $conn->prepare($Create_Event_Query);
                $Create_Event_stmt->bind_param('sss',$Event_Name,$Event_Date,$Event_Organization);
                $Create_Event_stmt->execute();

                if(!$Create_Event_stmt)
                {
                    Echo'<h2><a href="Events.php">Try Again</a></h2>';
                }
                else
                {
                    echo'Enter Row: '.$row_count.'<br>';
                    echo ' '.$Event_Name.' '.$Event_Date.' '.$Event_Organization.'<br> <br>';
                }

                $Create_Event_stmt->close();

                $row_count = $row_count + 1;
            }
            else
            {
                $column_headers = $data;
                $row_count = $row_count + 1;
            }
        }
        Echo'<h2><a href="Events.php">GO Back</a></h2>';
    }
    else
    {

    }



                            }
```

Comment: `var_dump($data);` before you try to assign your variables. Maybe there's a row that only has 1 value in the array.

Comment: Look at the data that was dumped when you get the error. Does it contain what you think it should? Are the [1] and [2] keys present?

Comment: Yes everything is accounted for.. I also moved it to it's own seperate php doc to see if there was something conflicting somewhere else and no dice.  
  
Here is what I get:  
    array(1) { [0]=> string(22) "Bulk Test 2 2/2/2017 3" } 
Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in

Comment: If you look at that, there is no keys for 1 and 2, just 0. I'm going to guess that you don't need that particular data (it looks like an information line), so you want to check if [1] and [2] exist before you try to insert.

Comment: Haha, I got it thank you. It appears when the CSV was saved it didn't properly distrube the Commas, thus when it read the file it didn't pull 9 cells, just 3.